# Missing variance term in likelihood estimation

Tags: normal-distribution, posterior

In [Murphy(2007)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), equation (10)

[image]

Why did the author ignore the term containing $s^2$.( Here, $s^2$ denotes the variance of the of the observed data).

From the looks of it , it doesn't seem like the term is actually constant yet the author has dropped the term. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Isn't the sample variance $s^2$ of the given data points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ known and fixed?

Comment: @dipetkov So in the paper the following things are mentioned -                            "Let us consider Bayesian estimation of the mean of a univariate Gaussian, whose variance is assumed to be known." I'm assuming that this means $\sigma^2$ is given not the variance of the observed data. ( Hence $\sigma ^2$  is considered as a constant)

Comment: There are two variance terms. There is the population variance $\sigma^2$, which is a parameter. Sometimes we assume it's known; maybe we have a good idea what the value is based on previous data/research/measurements. And there is the sample variance $s^2$. This is a function of the data; we have the data, so we can calculate the sample variance. That's equation (3) in the notes; check that $s^2$ is a function of the $x_i$s only.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. I somehow switched population and the sample variances in my mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dipetkov you can make that a quick answer  if you like.

Comment: I so not think the reason is because $s^2$ is a function of the data, but because $\sigma^2$ is assumed to be constant as in "*If $\sigma^2$ is constant*". This usually is an unrealistic assumption when the mean is unknown

Comment: @Henry I don't think I follow your point. Can you please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: @Henry It was my read of the question that the OP knew that $\sigma^2$ is assumed constant in this calculation but didn't realize that $s^2$ is always a constant. They didn't ask for example why the $(\sigma^2)^{-n/2}$ gets dropped. (Mishandling that term is actually more often a source of error.) Derivation by comment tends to not be effective, in my opinion. It's up to the OP to write out the math to understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by @dipetkov in the comments, we can calculate the sample variance directly from the data and hence it is an constant.